# Send data from Fragment Number 2 to Activity but instead it goes to Fragment 1

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i am going from:

```
Activity -> Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2
```

Now, i want to pass the data from Fragment 2 to Activity. I have created the `passDataInterface` and passed it in Fragment 2 constructor but Fragment 1 implements it since Fragment 1 is the one that called Fragment 2. And even if i implement the interface's abstract method in Activity, it never gets called.

**MainActivity.kt**

```js
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PassDataInterface {

    private val name = "Sagar"
    private lateinit var fragmentView: FragmentContainerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fragmentView = findViewById(R.id.fragmentView)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("name",name)
        val fragment = BlankFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentView, fragment).commit()
    }

    override fun onPassData(title: String) {
        println("Activity")
        setTitle(title)
    }
}
```

**BlankFragment.kt**

```js
class BlankFragment : Fragment(),PassDataInterface {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
        val tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv)
        val btn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
        val name: String = arguments?.getString("name") as String
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("name",name)
            val fragment2 = BlankFragment2(this)
            fragment2.arguments = bundle
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragmentView,fragment2)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
        }
        tv.setText(name)
        return view
    }

    override fun onPassData(title: String) {
        println("Fragment 1")
    }

}
```

**BlankFragment2.kt**

```js
class BlankFragment2(val passDataInterface: PassDataInterface): Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup ? ,
    savedInstanceState : Bundle ?
  ): View ? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    passDataInterface.onPassData("Fragment 2")
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank2, container, false)
    val text = arguments ? .getString("name") as String
    val b2 = view.findViewById < TextView > (R.id.b2)
    val btnDownload = view.findViewById < Button > (R.id.btnDownload)
    if (checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
    }

    b2.text = text
    return view
  }

}
```

**Output**

```
Fragment 1
```

I want the output to be

```
Activity
```

Please help, how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarcelHofgesang Updated, please check.